# Delete <div> tags inside a <table> in an HTML file using Bash

Tags: html, bash

The goal is to remove instances of `<div>` and `</div>` in an HTML file only when they are between `<table>` and `</table>`. All `<div>...</div>` tags outside the `<table>...</table>` tags would remain. The contents inside the `<div>...</div>` tags inside `<table>...</table>` would also remain.

Other challenges:

- There may be multiple tables in the file.
- There may be multiple `<div>...</div>` tags inside the table.
- There may be multiple `<div>...</div>` tags outside the table.
- The HTML might be either formatted or all on one line.
- It has to be a Bash solution.

Example:

(This HTML is not perfect because the system we are extracting it from offers no control over the output)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>text</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1>text</h1>
      <p><strong>text</strong></p>
      <ul>
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>text</th>
          <th>text</th>
          <th>text</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div>text<br /></div>
          </td>
          <td>text</td>
          <td>789</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div>
              <span style="display: inline !important">text</span><br />
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>text</td>
          <td>456</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div>text<br /></div>
          </td>
          <td>text</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

The result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>text</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1>text</h1>
      <p><strong>text</strong></p>
      <ul>
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
   <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>text</th>
          <th>text</th>
          <th>text</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            text<br />
          </td>
          <td>text</td>
          <td>789</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
              <span style="display: inline !important">text</span><br />
          </td>
          <td>text</td>
          <td>456</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            text<br />
          </td>
          <td>text</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can find many examples of:

- Deleting the tags (obviously), but this also removes those outside the table
- Deleting the set of tags while preserving the contents within, but this also removes those outside the table
- Accomplishing this with JavaScript (I need to use Bash or something easily called from Bash like sed, awk or Perl)

...but have not found a solution so far.

Thank you for any help or pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Could you clarify why you need to do it in Bash? Consider another common scripting language like Ruby, Perl, Python, etc.

Comment: So, you strictly want to use bash's own string manipulation and regular expressions and not call a single external program, not even sed or awk? Bash text processing and REs are somewhat limited, I'm not convinced this can be done.

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: @hcdocs: To complement the comment by joanis: Classical regular expressions can't deal with nested structures (such has picking up a certain nested set of parenthesis). In theory, you could implement a parser in bash, but this would be a major programming project, with no recognizable value.

Comment: @Matt F. Bash is what I'm most familiar with (not a professional programmer) - I have used Perl before though so I will try that - thank you

Comment: @joanis Sorry that my question wasn't complete. sed and awk would work fine. Thanks for asking this clarifying question.

Comment: @cyrus Thank you for the suggestion/information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of the comments above, you seemed to suggest Perl would do. So... this ugly Perl one-liner in a bash script should do the trick:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cat file.html |
perl -e 'sub removediv($) { $s = shift; $s =~ s/<\/?div>//g; return $s; } local $/=""; $f = <>; $f =~ s/(<table>)(.*?)(<\/table>)/$1 . removediv($2) . $3/gsex;  print($f)'
```

If you have Perl installed, though, it'll be much easier to read if you have a Perl script file which you can call from bash:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

sub removediv($) {
   $s = shift;
   $s =~ s/<\/?div>//g;
   return $s;
}

local $/="";
$f = <>;
$f =~ s/(<table>)(.*?)(<\/table>)/$1 . removediv($2) . $3/gsex;
print($f)
```

Here I'm being lazy and not applying all the usual recommended Perl niceties like `use strict`, `use warnings`, declaring my variables, etc. And I'm just reading the input from standard in. But hopefully you can adjust this to meet your needs.